# C#, about outputting positive numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, char, numbers, output

Is it possible to output positive numbers in c# with the plus sign '+', without writing a char code like this?:

```
Console.WriteLine("+" + 5);
```

This is what I mean:
For example, n = 5: I want the algorithm to output +5 like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnPDZ.png

Thanks for your help.

Comment: ...and negatives with `-`? What's bad with your current approach.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:+#;-#;0}", number);
```

It uses `WriteLine`'s built-in formatting feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like

```
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("+#;-#;0"));
```

Comment: You beat me to it...

Comment: Thank you very much. I used this code, it did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @wombie:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will help you.

```
public static class AwesomeSign
{

 public static bool IsPositive(int number)
 {
    return number > 0;
 }

 public static bool IsNegative(int number)
 {
    return number < 0;
 }

public static bool IsZero(this int number)
{
    return number == 0;
}

 public static bool IsAwesome(int number)
 {
    return IsNegative(number) && IsPositive(number) && IsZero(number);
 }

 public static bool printSign(int number)
 {
   if(IsPositive(number))
   {
     Console.WriteLine("+" + number);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think its too much to for? ;)

Comment: i think for it beginner. :)

Comment: A beginner should be reading so as to not re-invent the wheel into the landing gear for an Airbus A380. At least be aware of what the .net framework might be able to do for you. You want your *unknown Unknowns* to become *known Unknowns*.

Comment: Every peoples are not professional. I agreed your suggestion. Thank you.